# Writable Atomic property ... cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, properties, atomic

I have defined an atomic attributed property in my application but now find a new to override the setter so as to update some UI element whenever it is changed.  However, I get the aforementioned warning.  Is there a way to nullify this warning or if not, can I implement an atomic setter on my own?

Comment: Just declare a second atomic property privately and synthesise the getter/setter for that, then use it as a backer for your public one, accessing it in your getter/setter

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't implement only half of an atomic setter/getter pair because the definition of `atomic` on an `@property` is that *both the setter and getter are atomic together*.

You probably don't really want to be asking the UI to update on every property change anyway.  That tends to be way too granular.   In a typical app, there'll be something that triggers some new data to be loaded or existing values to be changed.